# Logging to a file isn't working in LogBack

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm having issues getting LogBack to write to a file even though I can see the output of the call in my console.

My project structure is:

```
main
    java
        folder
              // Classes
        folder
              // Classes
    resources
test
    java
        logback-test.xml
```

I've tried moving the `logback-test.xml` up to the foot of the directory. But no log file is created.

Below is my `logback-test.xml.`

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- "application-name" is a variable -->
    <File>./logs/logBack.log</File>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d %p %t %c - %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Just like `logback.xml` should be in `main/resources`, `logback-test.xml` should be in `test/resources`.

Comment: @Keva161, if _Kayaman's_ suggestion resolved your issue, could you please mark this question as answered.